# Storage in android app best ways for this scenario?

Tags: android

I want to develop an app that display health advice every day , what is the best way to store the advices, in local Sqlite or on server or shared preference?

Comment: This is a very wide question. please describe more what you want to do. you can store the informations as you want to. 
What is your need? Ability to update? Performance? Should they be editable? Who "asks" the questions?

Answer (score 0):

You can store them on a local SQLite database, however I would recomend you to store them on Firebase Realtime Database because that makes the data avalible even reinstalling the app, so that your users dont lose their progress.
You will need to register you and your app [here](https://firebase.google.com/).

Firebase DB's docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/